# Why does ruby output values like this?

Tags: ruby

Fairly new to ruby, can someone explain why these 2 things respond differently?

```
a=["A","B","C"]
puts a
A
B
C

puts "#{a}"
ABC
```

a.to_s returns the same output as the templating output, but shouldn't the simple "puts a" do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [this thread](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/227540), and for no good reason, Arrays have magically inconsistent behavior when given to `puts`.

> `array.each {|e| puts e }`
>
> is the same as:
>
> `puts array`

Answer (score 4):

The specified behavior of [puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/IO.html#M000474) is that it writes stuff out with a newline afterwards.  If it's an array, it writes each element with a newline.

When you do puts a.to_s, it does the to_s first (resulting in a single string) and then outputs that single string with a newline afterward.